# Selectize.js "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selectize.js

I've been trying to set up some selectize.js dropdowns at CodePen ([link here](http://codepen.io/nicolasjengler/pen/obXPxp/)) but the console is giving me an error.

[image: Console errors]

Right now I'm including the plugin's files in the settings of the pen, and they are called like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/css/selectize.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/css/selectize.default.css">
```

I know that I'm using the standalone version of Selectize, jQuery is also included in the pen's settings, using the "Add external Javascript" option in the Javascript tab. I'm not sure what's causing this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codepen, within the settings, you need to click on the "JavaScript" and "CSS" tabs and add your external resource URLs there. The HTML tab is for just that -- HTML only (meta tags and the likes).

Comment: TIL that external resources should be set on their own tab in the pen's settings.

That solved my problem, thanks a ton!